# Параллельный поиск максимального элемента в массиве строк

Tags: java, многопоточность

Мне нужно реализовать поиск максимального элемента с помощью многопоточности. Т.е. по идее в многопоточном варианте поиск должен работать в N раз быстрее чем в аналогичном однопоточном, но вместо этого многопоточный работает в 1.5 раза медленнее однопоточного. В чем моя ошибка?

Задержка в 1мс при сравнении обязательна в задании, но убрав ее ничего не меняется

```
    public static int findMaxMT(String[] lines) throws InterruptedException {

        List numbers = new ArrayList();
        int size = lines.length;
        int[] results = new int[size];
        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

        for (int i = size - 1; i >=0; i--) {
            int fi = i;
            Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    List num = new ArrayList();
                    int currentMax = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

                    for (String s : lines[fi].split("\\s")) {
                        num.add(Integer.parseInt(s));
                    }
                    for (int n : num) {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1);
                            if (n > currentMax) {
                                currentMax = n;
                            }
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    results[fi] = currentMax;
                }
            });
            t.start();
            t.join();
        }

        for (int n : results) {
            if (n > max) {
                max = n;
            }
        }

        return max;
    }
```

```
String[] lines = {
"706 575 855 882 595 778 477 602 147 467 693 793 120 384 256 866 548 367 910 848",
"206 232 632 315 743 823 620 111 279 548 210 393 791 815 519 768 168 484 780 705",
"709 127 900 171 189 590 563 317 600 975 892 296 166 353 863 312 399 872 964 591",
"302 869 679 157 419 485 325 290 739 149 407 648 688 474 311 177 318 611 348 557",
"559 283 171 352 698 759 384 822 598 410 802 293 962 859 812 153 436 392 869 167"};
```

Comment: Вы запускаете один поток и тут же ждёте его завершения. То есть работа выполняется последовательно.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov стоит ли мне обернуть цикл который запускает потоки в еще один поток? Чтобы на нем вызвать join. Или как лучше поступить?

Comment: *в многопоточном варианте поиск должен работать в N раз быстрее* - такого не бывает. как минимум используются ресурсы для организации многопоточности

Answer (score 1):

Вызови join после старта всех потоков, например, так

```
   public static int findMaxMT(String[] lines) throws InterruptedException {

        List numbers = new ArrayList();
        int size = lines.length;
        int[] results = new int[size];
        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

        List<Thread> threads = new LinkedList<>();
        for (int i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            int fi = i;
            Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    List<Integer> num = new ArrayList<>();
                    int currentMax = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

                    for (String s : lines[fi].split("\\s")) {
                        num.add(Integer.parseInt(s));
                    }
                    for (int n : num) {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1);
                            if (n > currentMax) {
                                currentMax = n;
                            }
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    results[fi] = currentMax;
                }
            });
            t.start();
            threads.add(t);
        }
        threads.forEach(thread -> {
            try {
                thread.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        for (int n : results) {
            if (n > max) {
                max = n;
            }
        }

        return max;
    }
```